# Scanner class java file not found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, readfile

Scanner Class couldnt find the file
I use NetBeansIDE, and the test.txt is in the folder path: D:\netbeans project works\ReadFile\src\readfile\test.txt

in the same folder the readfile.java exsist.
the code is as below.
It generates file not found.

```
package readfile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , FileNotFoundException 
    {  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));  

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())  
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());  
    }  
}
```

output:-

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
    at readfile.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: If the test.txt file is not present in the location specified by you "D:\netbeans project works\ReadFile\src\readfile\test.txt" it throughs FileNotFoundException.

Solution: You have to check before the file exists at that location else create the file first and then call scnner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following before creating `Scanner` class:

```
System.out.println(new File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

It will show you where JVM expects to find the file and whether it is the folder you expect as well.

Also check file permissions. But most likely it is a problem with default JVM directory.

Comment: thanks @tomasz-nukiewics for your help. I pasted the test.txt in the main root folder rather than the class folder. and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh you aren't specifying the full file path. When a file path is abbreviated (i.e. `test.txt`), java assumes that the file is in the *same directory* as the source code that is running it. So either specify the full path, or move the file.

Answer (score 1):

Move it to the ReadFile directory, i.e. the root of the project

Answer (score 0):

The `test.txt` file should be in the folder where the file `readfile.class` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this problem has been reported a long time ago, however, I have faced a similar obstacle and then the proposed solutions didn't work, thus I decided to post another answer.

Try using `try... catch` clause. For instance, only then my code has become compiled by NetBeans.

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me was removing .txt extension from the file name and using . to specify current directory (example shown below).

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("./test"));
```