# java can't scan from a text file even though it's in my working directory

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class scanners {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File testFile = new File("names.txt");
        // Scanner sc = new Scanner(testFile);
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

My output from this code is `C:\Users\steve\eclipse-workspace\a3`, and I have my `names.txt` placed in this folder. However, when I uncomment the code creating a scanner object, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*; 

public class scanners {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading the data file. Returning null for Scanner"
                        + "object. Problems likely to occur." + e);
    }

    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

}
}
```

For some reason this format works fine, but the one I posted before doesn't. I really have no idea why.

Comment: If you do `dir C:\Users\steve\eclipse-workspace\a3\names.txt` in a command prompt, does it list the file?

Comment: Is the file actually called `names.txt.txt` and the extension is just hidden from your view? Seems to happen on Windows machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385013/scanner-class-java-file-not-found

Comment: command prompt lists the file, and names.txt.txt doesn't work

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the absolute path of your names.txt with following:

```
System.out.println(new File("names.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

It will show you where JVM expects to find the file and whether it is present in the folder you expect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the text file directly in eclipse, in the package explorer right click on your project and Add -> unnamed text file, save it as names.txt.

You might also have named it names.txt with hidden filetype so it's now called names.txt.txt, that happened to me sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it is most likely that the code does not actually run in the directory you think it does. If you replace `File testFile = new File("names.txt");` with `File testFile = new File("C:\Users\steve\eclipse-workspace\a3\names.txt");`, does it work? If so, check your Run Configuration within eclipse to make sure you are actually running in that folder

Comment: no, the absolute path doesn't work, but a certain format i posted here does and idk why

Answer (score 0):

systemproperty 'user.dir' refers to the user's home dir. That's NOT the same thing as the 'current working directory', which is the directory that relative paths are resolved against.

In your case, the 2 clearly aren't equal.

You can either go with this:

```
new File(getSystemProperty("user.dir"), "names.txt");
```

or you can specify an absolute path and remember that in java backslash is the string escaper, so, that'd look like:

```
new File("C:/Users/steve/eclipse-workspace/a3/names.txt");
```

or alternatively:

```
new File("C:\\Users\\steve\\eclipse-workspace\\a3\\names.txt");
```

or if this names.txt thing is in the same place as your class files:

```
new Scanner(ClassYouAreIn.class.getResourceAsStream("names.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```